# How to change custom WordPress permalinks?

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom theme whereas the format of custom post is http://www.example.com/coupon/store-name/title-name

Is there a way to overwrite in whole site pages and change to http://www.example.com/deals/title-name

I tried Permalinks and Custom Post Type Permalinks and it didn't work.

Comment: Use URL rewrite .

Comment: Set the value of 'with_front' to 'false' in 'rewrite' argument while creating/registering your custom post type. This way permalink structure will not be prepended to your custom post urls.

Answer (score 0):

A custom post type is registered with the [register_post_type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) function and its URL slug is set with its [rewrite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#rewrite) arg. The good news is that you can use the `register_post_type` function to modify an existing post type.

You are going to need to:

- get the args which were used to register this post type. You can use the [get_post_type_object](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_object) function for this
- modify these as needed, that is, add your rewrite rules
- call `register_post_type` with modified args